# Talend OS - Define the nodes execution order inside a job

Tags: etl, business-intelligence, jobs, talend

Is it possible to have an order on the execution of nodes when executing a job ?

[image]

As you can see, i need to load the cities(wilayas) first before the towns(communes), so that i can create the town -> city 's hierarchy in my data warehouse.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right clic on the last item of the first node (TD_Wilaya with green arrow) > On componenet Ok > Click on the first item of the next node (TD_Wilaya with blue arrow).

Comment: To Translate: If you right click on the last component of the first node, you'll see a "Trigger" sub menu. In there, if you click "On Component Ok", it will allow you to link it to the next step.